# Jquery ajax / getJSON not ever getting to MVC ActionResult in Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

For some reason...maybe looking at too many different examples...this is one of those things that I am just not getting.  I am attempting to use the google maps api within an MVC app and then use JQuery to get data from the app to build the map with.  The problem is I can't ever actually get to a break point on the action result (unless I type in the url manually)...

In its most basic form the html includes an onload event...

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

which in turn calls my JQuery function...

```
function initialize() {
    $.GetJSON("/App/Map", MakeMap(mapdata));
}
```

I have tried the syntax a bunch of different ways based on things I've read like...

```
function initialize() {
    $.GetJSON("/App/Map", null, function (mapdata) { MakeMap(mapdata); });
}
```

And no matter what I do...I never get to the controller with it.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated because I am just not getting it.

Also if anyone knows any good books on JQuery that would deal with this sort of thing, suggestions are welcome because I think its time to get myself an early Christmas present ;)

EDIT:  I should also add that I have tried changing up the URL part of the request as well with no luck.  The page that is doing the requesting is the /App/Index with is set to the home page for the application

Comment: Does actually going to /App/Map/ print the json data?  If not, the problem is with that script.  It's also getJSON, not GetJSON, I think.

Comment: Have you inspected your web traffic with FireBug? What kind of HTTP response are you getting?

Comment: @tandu - Yes actually going to /App/Map does get the json data. I am thinking script issue because the script wont ever hit the break point in the controller.

Comment: @Andrew I have tried to step through it with firebug but it doesn't work real well for me with Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried to change the jquery method name:

the method is called

```
getJSON()
```

not GetJSON();

plus does /App/Map return a json string?

Here is the jQuery Docu on getJSON:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Also try to do it like this with the load callback

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 /* your getJSON call underneath this comment */
   alert("this should popup when the page loads");

   function initialize() {
      $.getJSON("/App/Map", MakeMap(mapdata));
   }

   initialize();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div>hello load page</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will give this a try a bit later and see if I can get this working.

Comment: It seems like this would work.  I did get to the ActionResult in the Controller once with it and then it stopped working.  It more seems some type of compatibility issue with VS2010, the default web server that comes with it, Firefox and Firebug.  The app just doesn't act the same twice with nothing changed...

Comment: If it doesn't act twice with nothing changed, you can disable the ajax cache in jquery to force it to do this, or use post instead of get.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use this code:

```
$.get("/App/Map", null, function(data) {
                    MakeMap(data);
                    }, 'json');
```

Also, in the ActionResult (JsonResult), the return value should be like the following in order to allow calls using GET.

```
return Json(whatevermodel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```